# Key Error 40 when using function from different Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using a random forest in a jupiter notebook to predict something. I have a separate notebook in the same working directory, in which I have specified the functions. I am able to use all functions from the functions notebook (for example data transformation functions), however I cannot use the specific function containing the RandomForestClassifier from sklearn. (Gives Key Error: 40)

I use:

import import_ipynb

import functions

at the beginning of the notebook to import the functions notebook, and then use functions.function_name to call the functions.

I have already tried restarting the kernels and reloading the functions.

## calling the function in the main notebook

```
clf = functions.random_forest_classifier(X_train, y_train, n_estimators      = 30, max_depth = 40)
```

## this is the function in the functions notebook

```
def random_forest_classifier(X_train, y_train, n_estimators,  max_depth):

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators, max_depth)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

return clf
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Looked up the signature:`RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=’warn’, criterion=’gini’, max_depth=None, ...)`

Your code `RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators, max_depth)` should be `RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators, max_depth=max_depth)`

Comment: @MarkLakshman You are welcome. Checking signature is a good habit.